# Call recording on an iPhone 13 Pro

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation, call, recording

I just bought a new **iPhone 13 Pro** to use as my main phone.

Are there any call recording apps, or ways of recording calls, regardless of whether they are free or premium? After searching through the app store, it seems all of the apps require me to start a three-way call, rather than saving the call locally. Because of my employment, I would not be allowed to make a three-way call.

I also tried quickly opening a normal voice recording app before accepting the call, however this resulted in the recording stopping. Since the voice recorder works fine when I am not taking a call, I safely assume this is a security feature.

I really like the phone, but sadly even Android can manage call recording.

Comment: It's not a question of "managing" anything, an app running on the iPhone does not have low-level access to system audio.  On an Android phone, apps usually do.

Comment: Call recording is such an important feature, furthermore it is not low level when I have a high level voice recording app running which the iPhone kills.

Comment: I've never seen anything in print, but I would assume Apple doesn't want to get involved with the mess that are wiretap laws in the US.  They're a single large target.  Android vendors are fragmented.

Comment: I disagree, the wiretap laws are common sense - at least one person needs to know they are being recorded, end of story. Many phones, even old Nokia phones, had the option to record.

Comment: No, not in the US.  Some states are one-party, others are two-party.  I'm not interested in trying to justifywhatever choice Apple made, I shared what I assumed was a plausible reason.  https://worldpopulationreview.com/state-rankings/two-party-consent-states

Comment: @MarcWilson Interesting, but I thought it just means the voice recording cannot be used as evidence, not that it is illegal resulting in fine/prison?